# Durability of SMD MEMS pressure sensors in pure oxygen enviroment

Tags: sensor, reliability, materials, mems, pressure

I have a question regarding durability/reliability of COTS SMD mems pressure sensors in oxygen rich (basically 100%) atmosphere under pressure of 1bar/1atm and temperature around **20C/293K**.

Sensor which might serve as example is **BMP280** from Bosh.

In theory it should work fine, because according to my research, top layer of sensing layer is silicon oxide.

Also very related to sensor are its connections to rest of circuitry. How proper reflow solder joints and generic solder mask react with oxygen rich atmosphere?

Comment: I suspect this question is best directed to the manufacturer.

Comment: I think it is very dangerous to assume that all MEMS pressure sensors are fabricated in the same way with the same materials. If some one tells you anecdotally that their sensor never failed in an oxygen environment it really means nothing to you. Ask the manufacturer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Manufacturers are very reluctant regarding providing "out of specs" operation characteristics. In quotes, because in datasheets it is stated that it cant operate in corrosive gasses but oxygen is corrosive depending from material. So, stainless cup might have some impact but silicon and gold interconnects are relatively inert.

Comment: @Felix and there might be a reason for that. I'll go further : the right way to source such a sensor is to work with the manufacturer to get something that meets your requirements.

Comment: I have no idea, but if I had to test it I'd run the temperature up to the maximums in an oxygen atmosphere and burn in/store for a week or so each.

Comment: Oxygen isn't helium but Ben at Applied Science showed how MEMS oscillators were severely affected by even small amounts of helium. Perhaps relevant?

Comment: @winny Can confirm, a few percent of helium in the office air totally killed my iPhone for days.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany For cooling, balloons or other mad scientist experiments?

Comment: @winny Some cold stuff.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Sure sure... Soon we will all hear "Greetings America! I . . . am . . . Spehro. Live like there's no tomorrow, because as far as you squallid lot are concerned, there very much isn't . . . . Behold! [camera switches views to a large contraption] The instrument of your doom! I call it: The Annihilatrix! And when it is completed, a million gigatons of thrust will propel the Earth, directly, into the Sun. So look upon my works ye mighty, and despair....."

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was thinking to create aging tests, but beforehand I wanted to make sure if maybe other engineers encountered same problem during design, so I could avoid it at least during initial design phase.

Comment: @winny I saw this video. I generally don't think that it would be problem because if so, atmospheric oxygen would have impact on readouts too.